# Dockerfile builds locally but fails on COPY step in Azure Devops pipeline

Tags: .net, docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, topshelf

I've containerized a simple windows service running on .net framework 4.8.  The app and container both build and run fine locally with this dockerfile:

```
FROM ourcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/net-framework-base:latest
WORKDIR /app

RUN cmd MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=Release
COPY TopShelfServiceInstaller/bin/Release/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["TopShelfServiceInstaller.exe"]
```

When I connect to the container locally in docker desktop, I see the files in the C:/app directory that I expect and can confirm the service is operating as expected.

However, when I try to run this dockerfile in an pipeline in Azure Devops using a windows-latest build agent, I keep getting the following error on the COPY step:

```
COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\docker-builder002424695\TopShelfServiceInstaller\bin\Release: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Any ideas why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

EDIT: azure-pipelines.yml for the build:

```
resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: net-framework-base
      type: git
      name: Container_DotNetFrameworkBase
  containers:
    - container: net-framework-base
      type: ACR
      azureSubscription: ---
      resourceGroup: ---
      registry: ---
      repository: net-framework-base

variables:
  - name: dockerRegistryServiceConnection
    value: ---
  - name: imageRepository
    value: "service"
  - name: containerRegistry
    value: ---
  - name: prod-container-registry
    value: ---
  - name: dockerfilePath
    value: "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Service/dockerfile"
  - name: tag
    value: "$(Build.BuildNumber)"
  - name: vmImageName
    value: "windows-latest"
trigger:
  batch: true
  branches:
    include:
      - feature/*
#pr:
stages:
  - stage: container
    displayName: New Docker Build
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
      - job: container
        displayName: build container
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        steps:
          - checkout: self
            fetchDepth: 1
          - checkout: net-framework-base
            fetchDepth: 1

          # this is the task that's failing
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: build container
            inputs:
              containerRegistry: $(prod-container-registry)
              repository: $(imageRepository)
              command: "build"
              Dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
              tags: |
                $(tag)
```

Comment: I don't think the `COPY` command does what you think it does. `COPY` copies files **from** the host file system **into** the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `COPY` command does what you think it does. `COPY` copies files **from** the host file system **into** the container. The reason it works locally is because you've built the code locally, so it's copying the version you built locally into the container.

What you *should* be doing is `COPY`ing the source code into the container, then running whatever steps are necessary to build the application. It's also a good practice to use [multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/) for this: You copy the source code to a container with the SDK and your build toolchain, build it, then copy the resulting output into a slimmed down runtime container that just contains a runtime environment with no source code.

Comment: In this instance the build agent is the host, though, right?  I was under the impression that the build agent checks out the source code from my repo, builds the solution on the agent so that the build artifacts exist there, and then I could just copy only what I needed to run the app from the bin on the build agent (host) into the container.

Comment: @Jerreck Although you *can* do that, you *shouldn't* -- anyone should be able to clone your repo and build the container from scratch with a single command without having pre-built the application code. If that's the approach you're trying to take, you need to ensure that your build pipeline is building the code. The agent doesn't automatically do anything, it's up to you to define your build process. Since you've shared no details about your build process, I can't provide any suggestions.

Comment: Gotcha, my dockerfile and azure-pipelines.yml both exist in the root of the repo for the service along with the .sln.  You can clone the repo and build the container from scratch by running docker build.  The yaml instructs the build agent to run the exact same commands I run locally.  I'll update my question to show the yaml as well.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that the **only** command you should need to run is `docker build`. You shouldn't have to run **anything else**. If your container is already building the application, then you don't need a `COPY` command in the Dockerfile.

Comment: Updated the question, but I think I see what you're saying now.  I'm having the dockerfile build the source code when I should have the agent build the source code, and that's why it's failing - the agent didn't build it so it has nothing to copy.

Comment: Yeah, that makes complete sense now.  Locally, I had already built the solution from visual studio (and forgot that I had done that), so when I ran docker build I was incorrectly thinking that it was also building the solution locally with `RUN cmd MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=Release` and then copying the build artifacts to the container, but that was totally not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add another answer to better explain what my problem was and how I solved it.  My problem wasn't a misunderstanding of the COPY command, it was a misunderstanding of what was being built where.  Here's the old dockerfile with explanations of where I was going wrong:

```
FROM ourcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/net-framework-base:latest
WORKDIR /app

# As Daniel said, the reason it was working for me locally is because I had already built the solution from visual studio.
# So this command wasn't actually building anything because nothing existed on this container yet.
RUN cmd MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=Release

# However, this was copying the files I had already built in VS locally.
# When this ran on the build agent in Azure DevOps, it would fail because the solution had not been built on the build agent.
COPY TopShelfServiceInstaller/bin/Release/ .

ENTRYPOINT ["TopShelfServiceInstaller.exe"]
```

Here's my new dockerfile using a multi-stage build with comments about what's happening when and why:

```
# First stage is building the app.  
# We do this with one container based on the .NET Framework 4.8 image that has the SDK installed on it.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8-windowsservercore-ltsc2019 AS build
WORKDIR C:/build

# Next we copy all files from the host into the build container.
COPY . .

# Then we run MSBuild to build the solution.
RUN MSBuild.exe /property:Configuration=Release

# Next and last stage is creating a container that will actually run the app.
FROM ourcontainerregistry.azurecr.io/net-framework-base:latest AS runtime
WORKDIR C:/app

# And here we're copying files from the build container into the runtime container.
COPY --from=build C:/build/TopShelfServiceInstaller/bin/Release .

ENTRYPOINT [ "C:/app/TopShelfServiceInstaller.exe" ]
```

The point of building this way is that it allows you to clone the repo and build the container with a single command whether you're working locally or running it in an automated build pipeline, again as Daniel has mentioned.